# mysql AS clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query, and from the date of birth field, and I working out the age of a person and then using `AS age` to create an age field.

My question is, is it possible to the match again that age field?

Something like this,

```
SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
       `candidates`.`first_name`, 
       `candidates`.`surname`, 
       `candidates`.`DOB`, 
       `candidates`.`gender`, 
       DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) AS `age` 
    FROM `candidates` 
    WHERE `age` <= 20
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

-----So I have changed WHERE to HAVING and here is my full query------

```
SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
       `candidates`.`first_name`, 
       `candidates`.`surname`, 
       `candidates`.`DOB`, 
       `candidates`.`gender`, 
       `candidates`.`talent`, 
       `candidates`.`location`, 
       `candidates`.`availability`, 
       `candidate_assets`.`url`, 
       `candidate_assets`.`asset_size` 
        FROM `candidates`   
        LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ON `candidate_assets`.`candidates_candidate_id` = `C`.`candidate_id`   
        WHERE `C`.`availability` = 'yes'  
        AND C.talent = "actor"   
        AND C.skill = "accents" 
        AND C.gender = "male" 
        AND HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <= 69 
        AND HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <=19 
        AND HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <=49
```

I get the following error,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_' at line 15

For the life of me I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Is it possible? Try it out. Writing that question sure took you a lot longer. (PS. I **think** mySQL is able to handle such cases, other DBMSs might not)

Comment: I don't think you can do that in MySQL...

Comment: I did try I got an error, assumed it may not possible, thought I back up the assumption via some experts....show me to the firing squad...

Comment: It's not clear why you're testing the age multiple times in your second query.  Anyone who's under 19 or under 49 is also under 69.  Are you trying to group them into age brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to wrap the original query as a subquery, and move the `WHERE` clause to the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, -- this is the original query
     `candidates`.`first_name`, 
     `candidates`.`surname`, 
     `candidates`.`DOB`, 
     `candidates`.`gender`, 
     DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) AS `age` 
  FROM `candidates` ) as innertable
WHERE `age` <= 20  -- this is now part of the outer query
```

---

clarification:  this DOES work in MySQL 5

note: this assumes that the original query works

Comment: Wow... Talk about complicating the issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing the `WHERE` clause with `HAVING`. MySQL won't be able to use indexes to optimize the result set if you do that, though.

Comment: hmmm never used HAVING before, how would I implment it in my query?

Comment: It should be noted that computation is way to complicated for MySQL to have any chance of using an index, so switching from `WHERE` to `HAVING` actually doesn't have a downside, AFAIK.

Comment: @sico87: Literally, by replacing 'WHERE' with 'HAVING'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html for full syntax.

Comment: @derobert: That's right, the only column in the `WHERE` clause is a computed value so there should be no performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Aliased fields can, however, be used in the `ORDER` clause as well as others. But not `WHERE`.

Comment: No, it is not true. You can use `HAVING` keyword to refer to aliased column.

Comment: That sucks, back to the drawing board

Comment: @sico87: Just use `HAVING`, there is no chance of using an index for that computation anyway.

Comment: Reading the question carefully, you'll see that sico87 asked **how** he can refer to the aliased field. You said he **can't**. I downvoted it since it's not helping him or anyone else since they'll think there's **no way** of referring to aliased column and clearly - there is. Replace where with having and it works. Not the best way but it's apparently possible.

Comment: @N.B. I think you're being a bit too harsh. Your first comment should  *help* any future reader if they completely missed my second line. My answer is correct - ***No**, you can not use aliased fields in the `WHERE` clause*.

Comment: Your answer doesn't **help** the person asking the question, it's obvious and I don't doubt your knowledge, you most likely know what the OP asked for and how to do it more than one way. If the downvote bothers you, I'll remove it but your answer still *isn't helpful*.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do this in SQL Server, but not sure if you can in MySQL.

```
select * from 
(SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`,         
        `candidates`.`first_name`,
        `candidates`.`surname`,
        `candidates`.`DOB`,
        `candidates`.`gender`,
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) AS `age`     
FROM `candidates`) as newTable
WHERE `age` <= 20
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To address the problem you're having converting to `HAVING`:

`HAVING` is a clause, similar to `WHERE`, but applied after the result is constructed.  If you go back to your first query, it would look something like this (borrowing the `WHERE` from your second query to make it more clear):

```
SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
   `candidates`.`first_name`, 
   `candidates`.`surname`, 
   `candidates`.`DOB`, 
   `candidates`.`gender`, 
   DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) AS `age` 
FROM `candidates` 
WHERE `C`.`availability` = 'yes'  
    AND C.talent = "actor"   
    AND C.skill = "accents" 
    AND C.gender = "male" 
HAVING `age` <= 20
```