# Filed in Mysql calculated from other calculated fields

Tags: mysql, database

I seek a way to be able to write something like this

```
select complicated_calculation1 as comp1, 
complicated_calculation2 as comp2, 
(comp1/comp2) as percent
from table
```

rather than writing it in the far more complicated way like this

```
select complicated_calculation1 as comp1, 
complicated_calculation2 as comp2, 
(complicated_calculation1/complicated_calculation2) as percent
from table
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903194/mysql-as-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the same line.

What you can do is:

```
SELECT comp1, comp2, (comp1/comp2) as percent FROM(
select complicated_calculation1 as comp1, 
complicated_calculation2 as comp2
from table) AS t
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume there is practically no performance loss for this either?

Answer (score 0):

```
no u cann't use this 

select complicated_calculation1 as comp1, 
complicated_calculation2 as comp2, 
(comp1/comp2) as percent
from table

u have to use only this 

select complicated_calculation1 as comp1, 
complicated_calculation2 as comp2, 
(complicated_calculation1/complicated_calculation2) as percent
from table

because rantime calculation can not be applied on Alis field name
```